# Individual indexes vs Covering index

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am tasked with improving the performance of a table that is totally denormalised.

It has 30 columns, but for the sake of simplicity, my example has 4.

```
CREATE TABLE (
   Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
   Location1 NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
   Location2 NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
   Location3 NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
   ...
   PersonId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL
)
```

This holds a hierarchy of locations, and at the end of the hierarchy, is a person assigned to that location.

Example data would be:

> 1. Building A, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
> 2. Building A, Ground Floor, NULL, NULL, NULL
> 3. Building A, Ground Floor, Section 1, NULL, NULL
> 4. Building A, Ground Floor, Section 1, Room 1, NULL
> 5. Building A, Ground Floor, Section 1, Room 1, 'Craig'
> 6. Building A, Ground Floor, Section 1, Room 1, 'John'
> 7. Building A, Ground Floor, Section 2, NULL, NULL
> 8. Building A, Ground Floor, Section 2, Room 1, NULL
> 9. Building A, Ground Floor, Section 2, Room 1, 'Peter'

So, in this case, we have 2 rooms, with their hierarchy. Room 1 in Section 1 has 2 people, and Room 1 in Section 2 has a single person.

Impressive table design, I know.

What I have done is requested that we ditch the `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. This has been changed to `VARCHAR(80)`. This now allows me to use indexes. The question I have is regarding the type of index to use.

TO find a parent of a selected row, I need to do:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE ISNULL(Location1,'') = ISNULL(MyLocation1,'') AND
      ISNULL(Location2,'') = ISNULL(MyLocation2,'') AND    
      ISNULL(Location3,'') = ISNULL(MyLocation3,'')
```

The vast majority of queries follow this sort of pattern. 'WHERE"ing the LocationX columns.

I'm unsure if I should create an index per column.... or, should I create an index covering all columns... or, one index per column, in INCLUDE the remaining columns.

So,

- index on Location1, an index on Location2.. etc

OR

- index on Location1, Location2....

OR

- Index on Location1 INCLUDE (Location2, Location3...) Index on
  Location2 INCLUDE (Location1, Location3...)

I'm not sure which direction to go in, to get the best performance.

Comment: `Location3` is meaningless without `Location1` and `Location2` (who cares if it's Room # 1 if you don't know what floor it is?) so you'll want to index all of them, from general to specific. Note: It's not a covering index unless all the SELECTed columns are in there as well, e.g. `PersonID`.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an index on `(location1, location2, location3)` -- a covering index.

However, you have a problem with the `NULL` values.  These are going to impede index usage.  To prevent that, change the default from `NULL` to `''`:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
   Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
   Location1 NVARCHAR(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   Location2 NVARCHAR(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   Location3 NVARCHAR(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   . . . 
)
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. There's currently a lot of logic that makes use of the fact that columns are NULL. That's a bit problematic. Is there anyway around this? i.e. Index on NULL columns? It sounds like my only option is a filtered index per column?

Comment: @Craig . . . Not a filtered index, because you still want to compare `NULL` values.  Instead, use persisted computed columns and index them -- and then use them in the query.  That incurs overhead for the additional columns, but it will allow the queries to use indexes.

Answer (score 0):

There should be one index on all relevant columns `(location1, location2, location3)`, but there is a problem with `NULL` values here.

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE 
    ISNULL(Location1,'') = ISNULL(MyLocation1,'') AND
    ISNULL(Location2,'') = ISNULL(MyLocation2,'') AND    
    ISNULL(Location3,'') = ISNULL(MyLocation3,'')
```

When you use `ISNULL` function (or pretty much any function) on the column value, the index usually can't be used. You can confirm by looking at the execution plan.

If you write a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE 
    Location1 = ISNULL(MyLocation1,'') AND
    Location2 = ISNULL(MyLocation2,'') AND    
    Location3 = ISNULL(MyLocation3,'')
```

the index will be used, but the query will not produce correct results.

---

Looking at how you wrote the query and your use of `ISNULL`, it looks like you are sure that `''` value can be safely used instead of `NULL`. Ideally, all those columns should be made `NON-NULL` and all `NULL` values replaced with `''`.

Since you can't do it, one way to deal with it is to create computed persistent columns for each `LocationN` column and then create index on those computed columns and use those computed columns in your query:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
(
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    Location1 varchar(80) NULL,
    Location2 varchar(80) NULL,
    Location3 varchar(80) NULL,
    Location1_  AS ISNULL(Location1, '') PERSISTED,
    Location2_  AS ISNULL(Location2, '') PERSISTED,
    Location3_  AS ISNULL(Location3, '') PERSISTED 
)
```

Create index

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX] ON [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [Location1_] ASC,
    [Location2_] ASC,
    [Location3_] ASC
)
```

Query

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE 
    Location1_ = ISNULL(MyLocation1,'') AND
    Location2_ = ISNULL(MyLocation2,'') AND    
    Location3_ = ISNULL(MyLocation3,'')
```

---

Another variation of this theme is to create a single computed column and merge all strings together with some delimiter and create an index on that single column.
It may be more efficient.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ADD
LocationAll  AS 
    isnull([Location1],'') + '|' + 
    isnull([Location2],'') + '|' +
    isnull([Location3],'') + '|' PERSISTED 


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_all] ON [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [LocationAll] ASC
)
```

The query would look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE 
    LocationAll = 
        ISNULL(MyLocation1,'') + '|'
        ISNULL(MyLocation2,'') + '|'
        ISNULL(MyLocation3,'') + '|'
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE 
    LocationAll LIKE
        ISNULL(MyLocation1,'') + '|'
        ISNULL(MyLocation2,'') + '|'
        ISNULL(MyLocation3,'') + '|' + '%'
```